# Where do files go for a Rails 4 C++ extension?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I needed to access a chip via SPI from Rails 4 so I wrote a C++ class that I wrapped using the rice gem. To get it all working I put the .cpp and .h files in a lib/classname directory, put the extconf.rb there, and compiled it and tested it with the rails console. Everything works fine. But I'm looking to structure it so it works well with capistrano and bundler. My first question is where should the C++ source files, extconf.rb, and the resulting .so file go within the Rails tree? Rails finds the .so in lib by requiring classname/classname, but is that optimal? Secondly, how would the compilation happen when the project is deployed by capistrano? Does bundler do it automatically as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See guidelines [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/), at section "EXTENSION NAMING"
2. Yes, one of the questions in [bundler's FAQ](http://bundler.io/v1.10/faq.html) is:
   "I Have a C Extension That Requires Special Flags to Install"

Comment: 1. I saw that page (and many others) and the concept makes sense, but the generated Makefile leaves the .so file in ext/classname and does not move it to lib where it would be loaded. Should I be doing something different or extra?

Comment: 2. I don't understand the relevance of the bundler FAQ. Is that how I might specify that I want the .so file under lib?

Comment: Perhaps, I misunderstood your 2nd question. The bundler link is just a proof that bundler does install gems with extensions. Whether it's local or deployed using capistrano doesn't matter.

Comment: I appreciate your help and am sorry if I was vague. What I want is when I deploy my app from an OS X MacBook on which the class cannot compile, I want bundler deploying to a raspberry pi to compile my class automatically. It does that for gems and I'm wondering if it can do it for my class, which is not really a gem. Or should I just create a capistrano/rake task that compiles and moves the .so to the lib directory?

Comment: AFAIK, bundler only handles gems. I guess you can use a rake task (BTW capistrano 3 uses rake). I'd put it in a rails initializer since the compilation isn't related to deployment per se.